Uncatchable exception when populating a WinUI-3 ListView (0xc000027b)
When I populate a ListView (or ItemsView) with the ItemsSource being a List<ApplicationModel.Package> object, a crash will sometimes happen when loading the control.
The crash chance goes up by a lot if I have an Image that uses the Package.Logo as a source.
When I triggered the control, I expected it to show all of the installed apps, their icons, etc. Which it did successfully, until I tried to scroll... which is when I was hit with the crash.
Using this code:
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="Program.AllAppsList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TITLE"
    Style="{ThemeResource DefaultContentDialogStyle}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Packages}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- High crash chance with this uncommented -->
                        <Image Width="64" Height="64" Margin="5">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Logo, TargetNullValue='ms-appx:///Assets/fallback.png', FallbackValue='ms-appx:///Assets/fallback.png'}"  />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, TargetNullValue='Unknown', FallbackValue='Unknown'}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublisherDisplayName, TargetNullValue='Unknown', FallbackValue='Unknown'}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>

using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Management.Deployment;

namespace Program
{
    public sealed partial class AllAppsList : ContentDialog
    {
        public List<Package> Packages { get; set; } = new List<Package>();

        public AllAppsList()
        {
            Packages = GetAllInstalledPackages();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static List<Package> GetAllInstalledPackages()
        {
            var pm = new PackageManager();
            return pm.FindPackagesForUser(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User?.Value).ToList();
        }

        private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
        {
        }

        private void ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
        {
        }
    }
}


Catch the Exception using an "Unhandled Exception Handler", and then you can see better what it is and what is triggering it in more detail.

Try the following:
public AllAppsList()
{
    var packages = GetAllInstalledPackages();

    // Magic block of code. Not sure why it works.
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        list.Add(package.DisplayName);
    }

    Packages = packages;
    this.DataContext = this;
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

Also, since it seems that some packages, espacially the ones installed in DevelopmentMode don't have a proper installed location, try filter them first:
public static List<Package> GetAllInstalledPackages()
{
    var pm = new PackageManager();
    return pm.FindPackagesForUser(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User?.Value)
                 .Where(package => package.IsDevelopmentMode is false)
                 .ToList();
}

